# What alternate we can use for data repeater control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, frameworks

What alternate we can use for data repeater control in asp.net to display the data.

Comment: If there is no other requirement, I think the GridView or just inline codes could do that..

Comment: ListView is arguably the best alternative !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice comparison of the different controls used to display data:

http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/09/06/comparing-listview-with-gridview-datalist-and-repeater.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[You may try to use Datagrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx)